# invalid attempt to access a field before calling read() 6

Tags: mysql, vb.net

it was trying to select id in the database but it said the error :
invalid attempt to access a field before calling read()
can you help me???
thank you

```
     Try
        MySqlConnection.Open()
        Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
        Dim query As String
        query = " select id from mcs.student where (last_name = '" & txtlastname.Text & "' and first_name = '" & txtfirstname.Text & "' and  middle_name = '" & txtmiddlename.Text & "')"
        Dim Command As New MySqlCommand(query, MySqlConnection)
        READER = Command.ExecuteReader

        READER.Read()
        lblno.Text = READER(0)


        Dim lbl1 As String = year.Text
        Dim lbl2 As String = day.Text

        lblstudentno.Text = (String.Concat(year.Text, day.Text, lblno.Text))


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MySqlConnection.Dispose()

    End Try
```

Comment: You **really** need to properly escape those values.

Answer (score 0):

The way you reading the data from your **ExecuteReader** is not correct using **MySqlDataReader**. You need to cast the data. Try the below;

```
Dim Command As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(query, MySqlConnection)

Reader = command.ExecuteReader()

lblno.Text = Reader.GetString(0) -- If Id is varchar 
lblno.Text = Reader.GetInt32(0) -- If Id is integer
```

Or you can proceed as below;

```
 lblno.Text = Convert.ToString(Command.ExecuteScalar())
```

Comment: i've tried it...it still not working but by the way thank you

Comment: Have you debugged and check if your Reader contains any records at all?

Comment: the Reader contain the record but when i will insert the record in the lblno it can't...

Comment: Try using `Reader("id")` instead of `Reader(0)`

Comment: Error 1 'Public Overrides Function Read() As Boolean' has no parameters and its return type cannot be indexed.